# What method can I use instead of delegatecall?

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

I see the warning `security/no-low-level-calls: Avoid using low-level function 'delegatecall'` when I use `delegatecall` function in my code.

I understand why it's not a good way, but I still need that functionality.

What method can I use instead of `delegatecall` when I need to keep my context and use storage in the called contract? Is there a safer way for this?

Comment: If you comment the line before like this:
// solium-disable-next-line security/no-low-level-calls
then you won't see the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning doesn't imply you can not use the functionality of `delegatecall`, you just need to be careful and to know what you are doing. There is no other method for this. Just be sure that you know perfectly the other contract.

Hope this helps.